# Android Move Image When Tilting Phone

Tags: java, android, image, accelerometer

I have an image in my view and I want to move it when I tilt my phone. It should look like the IOS wallpaper, when you move your phone. Some Android phones have this too. Is there any library or a good tutorial for this? Or does somebody know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe these two can help you: [tut1](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/hardware/sensor/android-accelerometer-example/), [tut2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125)
and i think the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) gives you a lot of information about the sensors (and the class sensor).

Answer (score 0):

Recently... I found a library called [gravity-view](https://github.com/gofynd/gravity-view)

This library moves the image based on the device.

**Inside Layout XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Inside Activity or Fragment:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gravityView = GravityView.getInstance(this)
                .setImage(bg, R.drawable.landingbg)
                .center();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gravityView.registerListener();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        gravityView.unRegisterListener();
    }
```